# "Trust browser" and similar things don't work

Tags: itunes, login, two-factor-authentication

Each time I login into Apple, either from web site or from TV or from iTunes, after I

1. entered my password,

I need to run and find my MacBook and

2. allow entrance based on geolocation
3. get pin code and and enter it into original device

If I counted correctly, it is 3-factor authentication.

The button "trust browser" has no effect: process repeats each time I login.

How to fix this, or how to get rid of multi-factor authentication? How do make it 2-factor?

Comment: On what device are you logging in? What OS versions are all devices using? Are you signed into AppleID on these devices?

Comment: @benwiggy there are plenty, including brand new Samsung TV; I don't think versions matter.

Comment: "Trust Browser" requires cookies to be set correctly. That's going to be down to the hardware manufacturer for something like a TV. BTW, that's 2FA not 3. The "factors" are 'something you know' [login details] & 'something you have in your possession' [a known pre-registered device], it's nothing to do with the number of clicks.

Comment: @Tetsujin I want to get rid of it. I don't want to run for my MacBook each time I open Apple TV+ page on my Windows desktop computer. Password is enough. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't switch off 2FA [you have two weeks after switching it on, but that's long gone].